# uploading n number of image to Firebase using Flutter

Tags: image, firebase, file, dart, flutter

Tried uploading two images into Firebase using flutter.The code only works for one image whereas it is coded for two images!there is no compiler error!

```
     File _image,_imageside;

   Future getImage() async {
   var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
   var image2 = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source:ImageSource.gallery);

   setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _imageside = image2;
    });

 }
    final DatabaseReference database =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("test");
    sendData(){
                final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
                              FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name).child('front');
                              final StorageUploadTask task =         firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
                              FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name).child('side');
                              final StorageUploadTask task1 =
                              firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageside);

    };
           _image == null  ? new Text('No image selected.')  : Text('Image selected'),
                        _imageside ==null? new Text('No image selected.'):Text("Image selected"),
                         RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: getImage,

                    child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                  ),
     RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,

                        onPressed: () =>sendData(),
                        child:
                        Text("Upload Data"),
                      )
```

Comment: share your code - then only it can be troubleshoot.

Comment: please check! @anmol.majhail

Comment: what i can see - You are using same `firebaseStorageRef` for both Images - hence you second image overwrite first Image. Assign `FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name).child('side');` to new variable & then upload task1 with new  `StorageReference`.

Comment: you got me! it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same `StorageReference` for both Images - hence you second image overwrite first Image.

Assign `FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name).child('side');` to new variable & then upload `task1` with new `StorageReference`.